# How to compile all .as files into single .swf

Tags: actionscript, compilation, actionscript-2

I'd like to compile several packages of actionscript 2 code into single swf, which i will be able later use as library.
I've tried to publish it regularly but it only compiles those classes which are being called within frames of .fla file.

While it is possible to define a variable of each class thus "using" them and compiling into swf, I don't think this is very clean and best way to do it.

Thanks you for any advice!

Comment: If you check the "export in frame 1" box in the library symbol properties, the symbol should get compiled in whether it's used or not.

Comment: yes, but i need to export compiled .as code, not symbols

Comment: If your Library symbols have their Base Classes set to as Classes, it will export the compiled code. If you don't need the symbols, then just use a Flash Builder Library project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

managed to solve my problem using mtasc compiler.
mtasc -cp "std_lib_cp" -pack "not_empty_code_package" -out result.swf -version 8 -frame 1 -header 800:600:30:FFFFFF

Answer (score 0):

You must use this syntax:
You cant use class keyword. so, you can add the constructor  with this format
this.class1 = function(){
}

to add static member you can use
this.class1.addProperty("myStaticMember", //getter function, //setter function)

to add property you can use:
this.class1.prototype.addProperty("myMember", //getter function, //setter function)

to add method you can use:
this.class1.prototype.myMethod = function(){
}

you can't add private variable. but if add the private variable member you can use:
var variable = 15;

your fla frames must only use 1 frames.